# "Ubuntu.Connectivity" is not installed

Tags: application-development

who can I install Ubuntu.Connectivity 1.0
on Ubuntu 14.04 to use it in my application on nexus4
I have used the example:
http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.10/Ubuntu.Connectivity.NetworkingStatus/

and when run it on my device
I have the error: "Ubuntu.Connectivity" is not installed

```
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.55ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.8.6-1ubuntu1) ...
Failed to open connection to "system" message bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
Processing triggers for udev (208-8ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 (2.30.7-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libunity-scopes3_0.6.4+14.10.20140828.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
(click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf)root@hafmed-HP-ProBook:/home/haf-med# apt-get install qml-module-ubuntu-connectivity
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-plugin-scopes : Depends: libunity-scopes3 (>= 0.6.0+14.10.20140804.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
(click-ubuntu-sdk-14.10-armhf)root@hafmed-HP-ProBook:/home/haf-med#
```

Please help me what I can do to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This API isn't available in 14.04, it was introduced in 14.10.  To develop apps for 14.10 phones, you should create an emulator or use your device and create a "Kit" in QtCreator to handle building and running it there.  You won't be able to run it directly on your 14.04 desktop.

See http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-sdk/using-device-kits/ for a short video on using Kits to run your app.